# Ordering MySQL results to obey parent/child

Tags: php, sql, select

I have a table like this:

```
ID   NAME                     TYPE     PARENT
1    Letters of Jane Austen   book     0
2    Chapter 1                chapter  1
3    Chapter 2                chapter  1
4    Chapter 3                chapter  1
5    Title 1                  title    2
6    Title 2                  title    2
```

I want to create a ordered form like this:

```
[]Letters of Jane Austen
  []Chapter 1
    []Title 1
    []Title 2
  []Chapter 2
  []Chapter 3
[]Another book...
```

In the database there are many books, not just one.

There any way to sort the query "SELECT" in this way? 
It is only a cosmetic issue and it does not need to do a multidimensional array or something, because I can put on the label their type and then to change their appearance depending on the type. But I need to fech the query in the right order.

P.D: sorry for my english :S

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: I tried to do it from php code with while + if or foreach, but I have not gotten it to work. But I am no expert in SQL, I thought it would be easier to bring a ordered query.

Comment: I'm not expert on mysql but if it's was sql server I would use a cursor in a stored procedure to do this.

Comment: This is not MySQL task. You need write some single-purpose PHP recursive function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think it's a good idea for database. Query would be kind of hard to it. Imo better - you select all books, write it to page in a streight order and just reorder it with js.

Html could be sort of:

```
<div id="books">
    <div id="book_1" class="book" parent="0">Letters of Jane Austen</div>
    <div id="book_2" class="book" parent="1">Chapter 1</div>
    <div id="book_3" class="book" parent="1">Chapter 2</div>
    <div id="book_4" class="book" parent="1">Chapter 3</div>
    <div id="book_5" class="book" parent="2">Title 1</div>
    <div id="book_6" class="book" parent="2">Title 2</div>
</div>
```

So js that does this hierarchy:

```
$(function () {
    $('#books .book').each(function () {
        var p = $(this).attr("parent");
        if ($('#book_' + p).length) {
            $(this).appendTo($('#book_' + p));
        }
    });
});
```

Check it at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3NTML/1/)

**Upd**

And you can reorder it on a backend with php if you want it work right with non-js clients, but solution won't be that beautiful :D

Answer (score 0):

I finally made ​​crazy, but it works, something like this:

```
select first type
foreach first type
__select second type where id = first type
__foreach second type
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of table uses what is called the Adjacency List Model. The following query will work for you:

```
SELECT
    b.`id`,
    b.`name`,
    b.`type`,
    b.`parent`
FROM `books` b
LEFT JOIN `books` b2 ON b.`parent` = b2.`id`
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN b.`parent` = 0
        THEN b.`id`
        ELSE b.`parent`
    END,
    b.parent;
```